# why isn't this NSMutableSet leaking memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

So I have this method that I see on an open source project, it just boggles my mind why this doesn't leak memory when I try to run static analyzer. Reason why I think it should leak is because it's allocating memory but never releasing it. It does release it everytime the method is called (because of the =nil). Can any one shed light for me?

```
- (BOOL)isValid(NSString *)name
{
    // Using a set so access is faster
    static NSMutableSet *exp = nil;

    // Setup the set once with AB testing info
    if (exp == nil) {

            exp = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    }

    if (exp != nil) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: no, it's not.. I don't have this hosted yet..

Comment: Does it complain if it's not a static? Given that exp is a static you'd not want it to complain. You're not leaking so much as retaining the object the static points to.

Comment: @MatthewElton so are you saying that static analyzer is not complaining because it is defined as static. I tried changing it to a non static and it still doesn't complain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the analyzer recognizes the `static` storage qualifier, and understands that it does not go out of scope (until termination, of course).

> It does release it everytime the method is called (because of the =nil).

not so. that happens the first time the method is called -- only once because it is `static`.

Comment: but is it actually leaking? question is should I release it at the end of the method

Comment: nope. i also added a bit about initialization. in a way, it is never deallocated until termination. but that is only one instance (assuming of course, there is no race condition). that's really how global data is expected to work, and the analyzer has not enough information to determine statically that the object could be deallocated earlier, based on its type. however, that would also change the return value so -- it's handled appropriately.

Comment: hmm...how is it static NSMutableSet *exp = nil; is called the first time only? when is it released then

Comment: @adit as far as releasing... that can't be the entire method, can it? that would only indicate that the method has been called. is the name added to the set?

Comment: because it is static, it is treated specially and initialized only once (the first time the method is called). it's never explicitly released. that is, the objects it holds will never have their dealloc called. however, the memory will be reclaimed at termination.

Comment: if it were not static, then it would be set to nil at each entry.

Answer (score 2):

The analyser isn't complaining because exp is a static. Try analysing again without the static and you'll get the complaint. (I've just verified this in Xcode - with ARC off.)

Think about what a static is and you can see why there is no complaint. You are telling the compiler that this variable is going to stay around pointing to the object. It's only a leak if there's nothing pointing to the object anymore and there's no chance of releasing the memory.

Comment: but just from seeing the code above.. it seems to be leaking, as I am allocating and I am not releasing it if I am not calling the function again

Comment: You're not leaking because exp is still pointing to the object. The object is still around and pointed to. That's a retained object, not a leaked on. A leaked object is one that's can never be released because you've lost track of where it lives. Allocating and not releasing IS NOT THE SAME AS leaking. Sometimes you want to do this intentionally, e.g. by using a static, cf. how singletons get implemented.

Comment: ok, I guess you just enlighten me that allocating and not releasing is NOT THE SAME AS leaking. Thanks for that

Comment: And see Justin's comment about static. A static is initialised once only.